# Use of same generic type in @param and @returns for a function

Tags: javascript, generics, jsdoc

How to annotate with `JSDoc` comment a `function` that accepts and returns object of the **same** *type*? Something like the following:

```
/** 
* Does some work and returns same type
* @param {T extends Object} src Source object 
* @returns {T} object of the **same** type
*/
function chainFoo(src) {
  // do some work
  return Object.assing({}, src); // just as example    
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You would just use the same type in both parts of the JSDoc, nothing wrong with that. You don't need the `{T extends Object}` bit, just `T` would suffice.

Comment: It's not concrete type but a generic. Consider the usage: `const obj1 = chainFoo({ choosen: 1 }).choosen;` should be of type number. But for `const arrangeAdate = chainFoo({ sheSaid: 'Maybe'}).sheSaid` it should be of string

Comment: If just a generic like Object the I would just use Object personally

Comment: Then object passing through the `chainFoo` function would loose it's metainfo about the type.

Comment: Yes but your parameter src is still an Object, and the function returns an Object, the contents of which can be dynamic so wouldn't make sense in JSDoc. You could use the Object<*> notation

Comment: The whole point is that some IDEs have support for JSDoc to deduct the type while typing ;) thus reducing the possibility of developer making a typo or other errors

Comment: Yes, but I don't think JSDoc or an IDE would be able to support something that can be entirely dynamic like that, I may be wrong and hopefully someone can shed some light about parts of JSDoc I don't know, but from extensive use of WebStorm I've not seen a solution to this problem.

Comment: `VSCode` as of now deducts it perfectly on my custom function decorated with the provided @template T comment

Comment: Nice. Glad you found a solution. Interesting to learn about template. Are you compiling your JSDocs? I'd be interested to see the output when using this method.

Comment: `VSCode` [example](https://pasteboard.co/HyXlONC.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to specify [@template T](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler#template-t)

So it looks like this:

```
/** 
* Does some work and returns same type
* @template T
* @param {T} src Source object 
* @returns {T} object of the **same** type
*/
function chainFoo(src) {
  // do some work
 return Object.assing({}, src); // just as example    
}
```